# Choose a template at runtime

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template that receives an integer type.

```
template<unsigned int N> void fun()
{
    ...
}
```

Assuming I know all the possible values of a variable (n), Is there a way to use a variable to choose a template at runtime?

Sample code to illustrate what I would like to do:

```
template void fun<0>();
template void fun<1>();
...
template void fun<MAX_N>();

void main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    fun<n%MAX_N>();
}
```

I know that it can be done with a long switch case.
Is there a more elegant way to go?

Comment: Templates do not exist at run time.

Comment: You can use type erasure, e.g. via std::function

Answer (score 3):

Similar to switch, you can generate array of function pointers:

```
template <std::size_t ... Is>
void dispatch(std::size_t n, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    std::array<void(*)(), sizeof...(Is)> funcs{{&fun<Is>...}};

    funcs[n % MAX_N]();
}

void dispatch(std::size_t n)
{
    dispatch(n, std::make_index_sequence<MAX_N>());
}
```